# Using Classes with Tkinter in python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Hi I was wondering what the difference between the first block of code (which works) and the second (which doesn't work).

Block1:

```
from tkinter import *      

class Temp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.var = self.userEntryFunc()
        self.var.pack()   

    def userEntryFunc(self):    
        return Entry(self.master)

def getval(x,y):
    cn1 = x.var.get()
    cn2 = y.var.get()
    print(cn1 + " and " + cn2)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
Name = Temp(root)
Name2 = Temp(root)
b = Button(root, text="pree", command=lambda: getval(Name,Name2))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Block2:

```
from tkinter import *      


class Temp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

    def userEntryFunc(self):    
        return Entry(self.master)

    def getValue(self):
        self.var = self.userEntryFunc()
        self.var.pack()

def getval(x,y):
    cn1 = x.var.get()
    cn2 = y.var.get()
    print(cn1 + " and " + cn2)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
Name = Temp(root).getValue()
Name2 = Temp(root).getValue()
b = Button(root, text="pree", command=lambda: getval(Name, Name2))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

block2 error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-111-c906f1aea49c>", line 24, in <lambda>
    b = Button(root, text="pree", command=lambda: getval(Name, Name2))
  File "<ipython-input-111-c906f1aea49c>", line 16, in getval
    cn1 = x.var.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'var'
```

My main goal is to have several objects of type Temp which have different tkinter widgets definitions within the Variable class, and use their value as a variable for future code. My problem is that I don't want to have 5 different conditions in my **init** function for doing this for different variable types (user entry, buttons, directory browsing). For example:

```
  if varName=="userEntry":
        self.var = self.userEntryFunc()
        self.var.pack()
  elif varName=="radioButton":
        self.var = self.radioButtonFunction()
        ...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For this sort of question, please include what error/problem you are getting with the code that is 'not working'. You can edit your question using the [edit] link. Also consider reading the [tour] page, to learn about the basics of this site.

Comment: Also, what is the `lister = [clientName, clientName2]` line for? In the 1st code, it creates an error, because neither `clientName` or `clientName2` have been mentioned. In example 2, that is fixed, however `lister` is still never used.

Comment: Thanks, super new to this. I cleaned up the code so it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st code sample, the `Entry` widgets are created by the `__init__` function (when the instance is created), through the `userEntryFunc` function, then packed. In the 2nd sample, however, the `Temp` class creates nothing on when created, its `getValue` function must be called externally.

The error you are facing happens because `clientName` and `clientName2` are actually assigned to the return value of `getValue`, not the `Temp` instance. To fix this, you need to assign the instances to variables, then call the `getValue` function, like so:

```
clientName = Temp(root, "Client Name")
clientName.getValue()
clientName2 = Temp(root, "Client Name2")
clientName2.getValue()
```

---

Also note that the line:

```
lister = [clientName, clientName2]
```

In example 1 will create an error, instead use:

```
lister = [Name, Name2]
```

Edit: Above problem has now been fixed